# Распознавание лиц на видео и поиск совпадений в базе данных

Tags: изображения, видео, нейронные-сети, распознавание-образов, распознавание

Стоит задача создать приложение, которое будет помогать охране супермаркета находить нечестных граждан.

На входе в магазин есть камера. Необходимо обрабатывать изображение с камеры в реальном времени, находить лица на видео и сверять их с базой данных, в которой хранятся фотографии. Выдавать оповещение при нахождении совпадения лица вошедшего в магазин человека с фотографией из бд.

Я никогда с подобными задачами не сталкивался и не знаю с чего начать. Может, есть какие-то готовые решения для распознавания лиц на видео и поиска совпадений? Вроде как в аэропортах и метро используют программы с необходимым мне функционалом.

Comment: Реализация на каком языке Вас интересует? Вроде есть что-то на `python`

Comment: @IgorSergeevich язык неважен. Подойдет любой, на котором можно эффективно реализовать эту задачу. Но предпочту C# если будет из чего выбирать, ибо его знаю лучше всего.

Comment: Использовать стоит технологию OpenCV, а также прочитать про обработку изображений чего нибудь, на сколько я знаю определение лиц происходит по носогубному треугольнику и крайних точек лба и челюсти. Тема очень обширная, освещалась очень много раз. Существует огромное количество реализаций, даже на python с OpenCV запускали под raspberry pi 2

Comment: А готово решение не рассматривается? Все это не так просто, существуют компании которые много лет работают в данной области.

Comment: Советую, очень удобный фреймворк http://www.neurotechnology.com/sentiveillance.html

Comment: @Unick готовые решения будут даже предпочтительными, ибо на разработку чего-то подобного в более-менее качественной реализации у меня уйдет непозволительно (для компании) много времени.

Comment: @mirupoko на хабре видел пару статей, где использовали ПО этой компании: http://www.visionlabs.ru/en/ , Например вот эта статья https://habrahabr.ru/company/croc/blog/308300/

Comment: @AGS17 ваш фреймворк очень хороший, а функционал демо приложения как-раз имеет все, что необходимо. Но он довольно дорогой. Может вы знаете что-то подобное дешевле?

Comment: @mirypoko не работал ни с чем больше. Да и думаю, врядли вы найдете подобное дешевле

Comment: @AGS17 оформите пожалуйста ваш комментарий в развернутый ответ. Скорее всего ничего лучше я не найду. Сейчас и использую пример программы с использованием рекомендованного вами SDK в качестве основы. Если ничего лучше не предложат выберу ваш ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Советую использовать фреймворк компании Neurotechnology:

**SentiVeillance SDK**

- Обнаружение лица в реальном времени
- Одновременное отслеживание нескольких лиц или объектов в на кадре
- Расширенное обнаружение и классификация людей и отслеживание транспортных средств
- Классификация по половому признаку, оценка возраста, распознование наличие очков и волос на лице
- Поддержка больших систем наблюдения за счет подключения до 10 камер на одном компьютере и быстрая синхронизация между сетевыми компьютерами
- Кроссплатфовренный SDK, поддерживающий несколько языков программирования

[Подробнее...](http://www.neurotechnology.com/sentiveillance.html)

Так же на сайте доступны для скачки 30-ти дневная [триал версия](http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#vl-surveillance) и [демо приложение](http://www.neurotechnology.com/download.html#vl-surveillance).

[Цена лицензии](http://www.neurotechnology.com/prices-sentiveillance.html)

Answer (score 9):

Как я понял, вам требуется готовая система распознавания лиц.

**The MegaFace Benchmark**

Можете посмотреть качество существующих алгоритмов по международному конкурсу The MegaFace Benchmark:

http://megaface.cs.washington.edu/results/fgnetresults.html
http://megaface.cs.washington.edu/results/fgnetresults_challenge2.html

Там же приводятся названия алгоритмов/компаний к которым вы можете обратиться, чтобы купить/получить доступ к API их алгоритмов (коммерческие решения) или получить исходный код (open source решения).

Из российских компаний хорошие позиции по качеству распознавания занимает NTechLab.

**Использование готовых API**

Также хорошим решением будет использование готового API качественного сервиса для распознавания лиц, чем писать с нуля свою собственную систему и выводить ее на конкурентный уровень качества (на что уйдут годы работы, т.к. для нормального качества распознавания недостаточно библиотеки Open CV, там надо внедрять полноценную 3D реконструкцию лица). Например, вот хороший вариант:

https://www.faceplusplus.com/

У них множество API на самые разные случаи распознавания лиц (Face Searching, Face Detection, Return Face Attributes, Return Face Details) с возможностью ведения собственной базы данных "подозрительных" лиц (Add Face, Remove Face, Create FaceSet).

В базовом варианте система бесплатна, в расширенном функционале они берут 0.001$ за запрос, а также можно купить лицензию на месяц/год. У вас приложение ориентировано на коммерческий сектор, потенциальные клиенты поймут, если вы включите в стоимость количество распознаваемых лиц (даже при ежедневном трафике магазина в 1000 человек дополнительные расходы у вас будут всего 1$).

**Алгоритм работы**

Можете использовать такое решение:

1. Направляем анализируемые видеопотоки на собственные сервера, где проводим их покадровый разбор и сжатие информации до получения набора различающихся между собой фотографий.
2. При помощи библиотеки Open CV вытаскиваете из получившегося набора фотографии лиц, по которым требуется провести распознавание.
3. Сверяем фотографии по схожести хэшей или базовым признакам (чтобы не отправлять на распознавание повторно фото одного и того же лица в разные моменты времени или с другого ракурса).
4. Если фотография лица уникальная, то отправляем ее через API сервиса (тот же Face++ или любой другой), получаем результат.
5. В случае нахождения совпадения по базе выводим предупреждение пользователям системы (через SMS, Push-уведомления или интерактивный web-интерфейс на WebSockets).

Отдельным моментом будет формирование базы "подозрительных" лиц. Если вы планируете ее делать "на лету" по данным вашего приложения, то можете сделать интерфейс добавления на основе снимка из видеопотока.